# Show that if $UT=I=VT$ for $T,U,V\in \mathcal B(X)$, then $U=V$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T\in \mathcal B(X)$. Assume that there are $U,V\in \mathcal B(X)$ such that, $UT=I=TV$. Prove that $U=V$.

**Attempt:** Take an arbitrary $x\in X$ and consider:

$$(UT)x=Ix=x$$

By our hypothesis. But,

$$x=Ix=(TV)x$$

Again by our hypothesis. But then we have that,

$$(UT)x=(TV)x,\,\forall\,x\in X$$

I was hoping to argue something along the lines of the operators $UT$ and $TV$ act exactly the same as each other on $X.$ Maybe using the linearity of the operators in play to reconsider $Tx=y\in X$ for each $x\in X$, but I think that this breaks down here.

I'm not sure if this is correct; I'm primarily concerned that it's a little too "hand wavy" with the points about "operators acting the same". Is there mileage in this approach? Or should I consider something completely different?

--

Edited as formulation of the intended problem was incorrect. Thanks to those who pointed this out.

Comment: I think the statement is simply not correct. you can change U all you want on $(ran T )^\perp$ and still get a left inverse. It would be correct in finite dimensions, though.

Comment: The note attached to the question reads: *"In other words, if $T\in\mathcal B(X)$ is both left and right invertible, then it's left and right inverses must be equal"*. So should it instead be $UT=I=TV$?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames Yes, it should have one on the left and one on the right.

Comment: @Joppy my thanks for pointing this out; I've since edited the question.

Comment: I might be being daft, it's been a while since functional analysis: is there anything stopping me from doing $U = U(TV) = (UT)V = V$?

Comment: @Joppy You are right. That's how it is proved even for general rings.

Comment: I think it might indeed be as simple as that, yeah.

Comment: @Joppy I do believe you have it. If you would like to write this observation as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the composition of bounded operators is bounded, we can do
$$ U = UI = U(TV) = (UT)V = IV = V$$

Answer (score 0):

This only gives a counterexample to the question before the edit. The edited question is answered in the comments.

Let $T: \ell_2(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ be defined by 
$T((x_{1}, x_2, \dots, )) = (0, x_{1}, x_2, \dots, )$.

Let $U : \ell_2(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ be defined by 
$U((x_{1}, x_2, \dots, )) = (x_2, x_3, \dots, )$.

Let $V : \ell_2(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ be defined by 
$V((x_{1}, x_2, \dots, )) = (x_2 + x_1, x_3, \dots, )$.

You have $UT = I = VT$ but $U \neq V$.